Validating a valid DateTime Format in C#
I'm currently working on validating various DateTime formats provided manually by users to ensure their validity within my application. My current approach involves converting a sample DateTime object to a formatted string using the provided format and then parsing it back to compare with the original sample. While this method successfully validates some scenarios, it might not cover all edge cases.
Could you suggest any improvements or alternative approaches I could consider to enhance the validation process? Additionally, I will be sharing a list of DateTime formats I've tested along with their outcomes for reference.
I appreciate any advice or insights you can provide. Thank you!
Here's the logic I've implemented for checking the validity of a date/time format:
private static bool IsValidDateTimeFormat(string dateTimeFormat)
{
    try
    {
        // Step 1: Create a sample DateTime object
        DateTime sampleDateTime = new DateTime(2024, 6, 13, 12, 34, 56);

        // Step 2: Convert the sample DateTime object to a string using the provided format
        string formattedDateString = sampleDateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        // Print the formatted string for debugging purposes
        Console.WriteLine(formattedDateString);

        // Step 3: Try to parse the formatted string back to a DateTime object
        DateTime parsedDate;
        bool isValidFormat = DateTime.TryParseExact(formattedDateString, dateTimeFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
     
        // Additional logical check: Ensure the parsed date matches the sample date
        return isValidFormat && sampleDateTime == parsedDate;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        // If the format string is invalid, DateTime.ToString will throw a FormatException
        return false;
    }
}


This is the outcome I got:
2024/06/13 12:34:56        Format 1 is valid: True
13-06-2024 12:34:56        Format 2 is valid: True
06/13/24                   Format 3 is valid: False
2024/06/13                 Format 4 is valid: False
12:34:56                   Format 5 is valid: False
12:34:56 PM                Format 6 is valid: False
2024-06-13T12:34:56        Format 7 is valid: True
June 13, 2024              Format 8 is valid: False
Jun 13, 2024               Format 9 is valid: False
2024.06.13 12:34:56        Format 10 is valid: True
06/13/2024 12:34:56        Format 11 is valid: True
2024/06/13 12:34:56 PM     Format 12 is valid: True
24-06-13 12:34:56          Format 13 is valid: True
13/06/2024 12:34:56        Format 14 is valid: True
June 2024                  Format 15 is valid: False
06/13/24 12:34:56 PM       Format 16 is valid: True
240613123456               Format 17 is valid: True
06-13-2024                 Format 18 is valid: False
Despite some of these formats being valid, I'm encountering incorrect outcomes for a few cases that are actually valid formats. This discrepancy arises because they do not match the sample DateTime object.
Some such formats are:
06/13/24       Format is valid: False
2024/06/13     Format is valid: False
June 13, 2024  Format is valid: False
Jun 13, 2024   Format is valid: False
06-13-2024     Format is valid: False

My guess would be due to UTC handling as you aren't explicitly setting the DateTimeKind when you construct the DateTime value for step 1, so the Kind values don't match, so they aren't considered equal.

Those aren't valid formats for the InvariantCulture which is essentially the en-US culture. They're valid is some other culture. And some of these are impossible to parse with any certainty, like 06/13/24. Even assuming that's mm/dd/yy, is that 1924 or 2024? You can't claim it's one or the other without risking bad data

Note, codereview.stackexchange is for working code that is seeking improvements

@flackoverstow this isn't seeking improvements. The question's code is failing to parse non-US formats

@ALTHAF make your life easy; decide on some typical formats that do not result in ambiguity and let the user pick one. Giving users massive freedom of choice is generally a bad idea

What's the point of IsValidDateTimeFormat anyway? To verify that a specific parse format is valid in a culture? You can use the culture's DateTimeFormat property  to get a DateTimeFormatInfo object and then DateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns()

In desktop applications not passing a CultureInfo uses the current thread's (ie the user's) locale, available through the Thread.CurrentCulture. You can change both the UI's and current thread's culture eg through configuration settings or a user choice. Validation tools use that culture by default. Or you can have the use pick a culture and use that explicit CultureInfo in all localized methods. IsValidDateTimeFormat doesn't seem to server a useful validation purpose, unless you intend to store dateTimeFormat as data for later use

@MartinCostello DateTimeKind is ignored in DateTime comparison
new DateTime(2024,1,1,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc) == new DateTime(2024,1,1,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Local) yields true;

If you hope to write something ignoring culture i have to tell you that that won't work. The same format might means something else in a different culture. And your user might think about the format differently then your code expects. The typically "mm/dd/yy" vs "dd/mm/yy" thing.
